# Manhua in which the female lead is the stepmother of the villain

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In this story, the female lead is the stepmother of the villain of the novel into which she is reincarnated. She tries to change his fate or way, as well as becoming the duke's wife.

Comment: This is incredibly brief and likely to match a few manhuas, can you remember anything else at all about this that you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like *[I Became the Villain's Mother](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-became-the-villains-mother)*.

[image]

A woman is summoned into a novel she's previously read, and is placed in the role of the villain's stepmother. At the point in the novel she arrives in, the villain is still a boy, but she knows he's fated to kill her when he's older, so she resolves to change his future by guiding him in a better direction. She's also the wife of a duke in the novel, another thing mentioned in your description.

Synopisis from Anime-Planet:

> Summoned into her favorite novel as the infamous Duchess Roselia Chade, Haena is bathed in riches, power, and a family of her own. Life couldn’t be better, save for the small detail that her beloved stepson, Einspanner Chade, is also the evil mastermind destined to kill her. At this point in the story Ein is still just an adorable child yet to reach his cruel awakening, and so Roselia is determined to stop him from becoming a ruthless killer. But with the duke getting in her way and trying to poison his own son, safely raising a child that was primed for villainy may prove harder than she originally thought. The survival of both mother and child depends on whether Roselia can successfully rewrite their tragic ending.